# Connect a separate router with its own network to main router for internet access

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

Please guide me in connecting the following.

Main router Xiaomi ax3000 got the internet access to ISP. This router’s network- 192.168.31.5-254
I’ve got another router (192.168.1.1-100) which I’m trying to connect to main router via cable to get access to internet.
Both networks should be able to communicate with each other.

Searching internet for help, all mentioning configuration on routing table of both routers. I managed to add entry to the secondary router, however cannot get a way to get to the routing table of the Xiaomi router.
Adding the entry to the secondary router, I managed to get secondary router on the Xiaomi network, however no internet access from secondary network. Also do not have access to the computers/ media devises on secondary network from Xiaomi network.

My main reason in for the two networks:

1. Secondary network:
   a) got guest network for visitors. I want to be able to limit their bandwidth.
   b) printers/ computers/ media device which I would like to have access to from main network.
   c) secondary devices needs internet access
   d) limit bandwidth where necessary.
2. Main network:
   a) connected to internet.
   b) my security cameras running on this network.
   c) ip phone’s connected
   d) other devices which needs network priory.

Hope my above explanation make sense. Any suggestions please .

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Why don't you configure the second router as a bridge/access-path so to have one unified network?

Comment: Harrymc - thank you for the reply. 
Using a bridge method - will that not causing the network to be slow?

Comment: No, it will actually speed it up, since you will not have a double-NAT on the second router. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc - Thank you. I’ll go that route again. My previous setup was like that and the system got very slow therefore the upgrade of the main router.